# Can I use controller methods in a observer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, controller, observer-pattern

I need to refer to a controller method from a cache observer, How can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it, then something goes wrong with architecture. It breaks MVC pattern because observers bind to models, and we should call model methods from controller and not vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

an observer binds to models, at least you can write some custom code in lib, then reuse it in obsever. by the way it may depend from what you're doing